# Can I travel on a valid Canadian visa in an old/expired passport?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, passport-renewals, ethiopian-airlines

I recently renewed my passport in February 2020. I have a valid Canadian visitor visa in my old passport (with expiry date 30/09/2020, the visa also expires 30/09/2020).

I had planned to travel to Canada from Mumbai airport with Ethiopian Airlines on 11/03/2020, but since I don't have visa in my new passport, they didn't allow me to travel. So what is the next step to do?

Comment: Did you have both passports with you and did you show them the visa?

Comment: Next step : buy a new ticket and get your old passport with yourself thistime.

Comment: Alternatively, get a new visa in your new passport.